# Generic reply from agent/mailboxprocessor?

Tags: asynchronous, f#, agent

I currently have an agent that does heavy data processing by constantly posting "work" messages to itself.

Sometimes clients to this agent wants to interrupt this processing to access the data in a safe manner.

For this I thought that posting an async to the agent that the agent can run whenever it's in a safe state would be nice. This works fine and the message looks like this:

```
type Message = |Sync of Async<unit>*AsyncReplyChannel<unit>
```

And the agent processing simply becomes:

```
match mailbox.Receive () with
| Sync (async, reply) -> async |> Async.RunSynchronously |> reply.Reply
```

This works great as long as clients don't need to return some value from the async as I've constrained the async/reply to be of type unit and I cannot use a generic type in the discriminated union.

My best attempts to solve this has involved wrapper asyncs and waithandles, but this seems messy and not as elegant as I've come to expect from F#. I'm also new to async workflows in F# so it's very possible that I've missed/misunderstood some concepts here.

So the question is; how can I return generic types in a agent response?

Comment: of course you can use generics in the Message: `type Message<'a> = Sync of ...*AsyncReplyChannel<'a>` you just probably need to *bubble* this all up...

Comment: btw: why the work with the `Async<unit>` when you just run it with `RunSynchronously` anyway - a simple `() -> ()` will do as well in this case (or if you want it generic: `type Message<'a> = Sync of ((() -> 'a) *  AsyncReplyChannel<'a>)`

Comment: another thing: are you using the out-of-the-box `MailboxProcessor`? Because `.Receive` should be async (so it should not work with `match`) - in this case passing a async-workflow would make sense

Comment: Huh, I swear I tried to use a generic parameter in the union, that solves it I guess (however it does look a little messy with the type parameter defined in the Message definition when it's just used by a single of the many cases I have).

Comment: About the async vs ()->(), well, not really, I'm still messing with my architecture, my thinking is that since it's up to the agent how and when the task should be run and all the client know is "it will be run sometime in the future on some other thread", I thought the async would be a nice semantic choice. It also makes it easy for the client to switch synchronization contexts and such for updating ui.

Comment: And for the example, that's just a dry-coding error, in my real code I bind the result using let! before matching :-)

Comment: Spoke to soon! Is it possible to define the mailboxprocessor with a wildcard in the message generic type? The following gives me an error: `type MyAgent = MailboxProcessor<Message<_>>`

Comment: that is what I meant by *bubbling* - you now have to make `MyAgent` generic as well: `type MyAgent<'a> = MailboxProcessor<Message<'a>>`  - there is no easy way to get around this, the easiest one I could give is to change the message-type into just `type Message = Sync of Async<unit>` and wrap the computation as a closure in the async-workflow - ofc you have to create this AWF given a `AsyncReplyChannel` and call it in there - but then only the constructor function needs to be generic and the agent would not care at all (and just run the workflow)

Comment: **but** if you need the result of the first component of your message inside the agent for some things (and to be honest: if you don't need it there then why bother using the agent in the first place?) you are out of luck - obvious you have to know the type then

Comment: this is by the way the reason why you use ADT for the message, so you can have more than one ;)

Comment: and you can obvious always fall back to OOP and use some base-type as common ground instead of a full-generic function

Comment: Making the agent generic is not possible as a single agent should be able to handle different types. I'd love to continue this in the chat btw, it's very useful to get this kind of feedback!

Comment: sadly it's rather late here and I am about to call it a day - maybe tomorrow

Comment: That's fine (late here too), sleep tight and thanks for the help! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing that makes this difficult is that, in your current version, the agent would somehow have to calculate the value and then pass it to the channel, without knowing what is the type of the value. Doing that in a statically typed way in F# is tricky.

If you make the message generic, then it will work, but the agent will only be able to handle messages of one type (the type `T` in `Message<T>`).

An alternative is to simply pass `Async<unit>` to the agent and let the caller do the value passing for each specific type. So, you can write message & agent just like this:

```
type Message = | Sync of Async<unit>

let agent = MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox -> async {
  while true do
    let! msg = inbox.Receive ()
    match msg with
    | Sync (work) -> do! work })
```

When you use `PostAndReply`, you get access to the reply channel - rather than passing the channel to the agent, you can just use it in the local `async` block:

```
let num = agent.PostAndReply(fun chan -> Sync(async { 
  let ret = 42 
  chan.Reply(ret) }))

let str = agent.PostAndReply(fun chan -> Sync(async { 
  let ret = "hi"
  chan.Reply(ret) }))
```

Comment: Ah, very clever to use the replychannel this way!